# NetworkX: Adjacency Matrix of partially failed graphs/networks

Tags: python, matrix, networkx, adjacency-matrix

Recalling that the Adjacency Matrix gives us `1` if two nodes are connected and `0` otherwise, I wanted to compute one matrix for a regular graph with all its nodes `active`, and one *for the same graph* where a few nodes have `failed`.

Let's consider a Lattice Network of `2x2` nodes. Its Adjacency Matrix **(A)** is:

```
0  1  1  0
1  0  0  1
1  0  0  1
0  1  1  0
```

resulting in this graph:
[image]

Now, let's remove node `0`:

```
G.remove_node(0)
```

This is what the new Adjacency Matrix **(A1)** looks like:

```
0  0  1
0  0  1
1  1  0
```

returning this graph:
[image]

Now, the two Matrices are noticeably different in terms of size.

**My question**: how can I make sure that Matrix **A1** has the same size of Matrix **A**? Which is to say, if node `0` is not going to be present because it has failed, I want a `0` to be placed in **A1** *in correspondence of the `0-th` row and column*, so that the size of the matrix remains unaltered. I need to do this for purposes of comparison and computation. But to do this I assume I need to access the function creating the adjacency matrix. Can I do it in a simpler way?

Example with node `0` failed:

```
0  0  0  0
0  0  0  1
0  0  0  1
0  1  1  0
```

This is how I create the `2x2` network and generate the Adjacency Matrix:

```
import networkx as nx

N=2
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i,j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
inds=labels.keys()
vals=labels.values()
inds.sort()
vals.sort()
pos2=dict(zip(vals,inds))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos2, with_labels=True, node_size = 200)

A=nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
A.toarray()

#G.remove_node(i) to remove node i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a little research and the advice of Joel, I've come up with this method. I want to post it here so that anyone who has the will can propose improvements.

For a regular `3x3` network, this is how we can obtain the adjacency matrix in a righteous way:

```
#Create the graph (see question above)
A=nx.adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist=range(N*N))
A=A.todense()
```

This yields a `N^2xN^2` matrix where each row/column corresponds to a specific node (using `nodelist` allows to have the rows/columns to be printed out sorted `0` to `K` where `K` is the total number of nodes):

```
[[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]]
```

[image]

If node `0` had failed, we would have to replace its connections (`1`) with absent connections (`0`), while preserving the size of the adjacency matrix. In this case, row `0` and column `0` would be filled with `0`. My solution then goes as follows:

```
P=K #Total number of nodes before failures

def nodes_connected(i, j):
     try: 
        if i in G.neighbors(j):
            return 1
     except nx.NetworkXError:
        return False          

A1=numpy.zeros((P*P,P*P))

for i in range(0,P*P,1):
    for j in range(0,P*P,1):              
        if i not in G.nodes():
            A1[i][:]=0
            A1[:][i]=0
        elif i in G.nodes():
            A1[i][j]=nodes_connected(i,j)
                A1[j][i]=A1[i][j]
for i in range(0,P*P,1):
    for j in range(0,P*P,1):
            if math.isnan(A1[i][j]):
                A1[i][j]=0              
print(A1)
```

This yields the following:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

Matrix A1 now tells us that node `0` has no connections whatsoever. It also tells us, similar to matrix A, that node `1` is connected to nodes `2` and `4`.

If anyone has corrections to propose, please feel welcome to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Try  `G.remove_edges_from(G.edges(0))` which will remove all of the edges of `0` rather than the entire node.  Then generate the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Good to know. But what if my "failed" network comes from a `pickle` I call back in and process to generate the adjacency matrix? Same thing as my example with 3 nodes, only that nodes were not deleted by using `G.remove_node(0)`, but based on different criteria. The adj matrix of my pickle has a smaller size if compared to that of the original network. See what I mean?